# Prime numbers $(x,c,p)$ such that $x^3-p x^2-cx-5c=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How should I proceed to find all prime numbers $x,c,p$ such that
$$x^3-px^2-cx-5c=0$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x^3-px^2-cx-5c=0$, then $x$ divides $5c$. Since $x$ and $c$ are prime, we have the two possibilities $x=c$ and $x=5$.

Suppose $x=c$. Substitute.  We get $c^3-(p+1)c^2-5c=0$, so $c^2-(p+1)c-5=0$, so $c$ divides $5$, so $c=5$.  Therefore definitely $x=5$.

Substitute. We get $125-25p-10c=0$. Since $25$ divides $10c$, it follows that $c=5$. Thus $p=3$.

Comment: can you please explain why $25$ divides $5c$ ? I can only see $25$ divides $10c$

Comment: @Belgi: Thanks. I should have written $25$ divides $10c$. Fixed. It still follows that $c=5$.